What is the current behavior of selfdestruct in the EVM as of 2024?
I'm looking to understand the current behavior and gas implications of the selfdestruct opcode in the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) as of 2024.
Specifically, I’m interested in:

Gas Costs: Have there been any changes to the gas cost associated with selfdestruct in recent Ethereum upgrades, such as those introduced by EIPs 6049, 6780, or 4758?

Behavior: Does selfdestruct still fully remove contract code and storage, or have there been any recent modifications that alter its functionality?

Best Practices: Given any recent changes, what are the current best practices for using selfdestruct in smart contract development?


I’m primarily concerned with how these factors might affect contract deployment and security considerations. References to specific Ethereum Improvement Proposals (EIPs) or official documentation would be greatly appreciated.

evm.codes does an excellent job of describing the 0xFF (SELFDESTRUCT) operation and explaining the various GAS costs.
1. GAS costs
Changing the SELFDESTRUCT behavior didn't change its GAS cost. It can range from 5000 to 32600.

The static gas is 5000. If a positive balance is sent to an empty
account, the dynamic gas is 25000. An account is empty if its balance
is 0, its nonce is 0 and it has no code. Additionally, if address is
cold, there is an additional dynamic cost of 2600. See section access
sets. There is no additional cost otherwise.

So the cost depends on some parameters, and you can try the "Estimate your gas cost" feature on evm.codes, but here the estimation in a table for convenience:
Is the current account balance empty?   Y Y N    Y Y N     N       N
Is the beneficiary account empty?       Y N N    Y N N     Y       Y
Is the beneficiary account cold?        N N N    Y Y Y     N       Y
GAS COST                                5000     7600    30000   32600

2. Behavior
SELFDESTRUCT still completely removes contract code and storage, but now the operation is only allowed in the same transaction that created the contract.

From cancun behavior: send all Ether in the account to the target. If
executed in the same transaction a contract was created, or
pre-Cancun, the current account is registered to be destroyed, and
will be at the end of the current transaction. The transfer of the
current balance to the given account cannot fail. In particular, the
destination account code (if any) is not executed, or, if the account
does not exist, the balance is still added to the given address.

3. Best practice
I think this is subjective, like all best practices, so this is my opinion.
Originally, the SELFDESTRUCT was meant to be a way to incentivize developers not to bloat the network state.
That is, you could deploy a smart contract, use it for a while, and then delete it.
You could also create a business logic operation "on the fly," running some business logic at deployment time, but then deleting the contract in the same transaction because you didn't need the logic to live there forever.
I was a big fan of this operation, and I was against nerfing it for the first use case, but the community decided to do it with these assumptions:

developers didn't use it as much as originally expected
for future-proofing reasons. From EIP-4758: The SELFDESTRUCT opcode requires large changes to the state of an account, specifically the removal of all code and memory. This will not be possible with Verkle trees in the future: Each account will be stored in many different account keys with no obvious connection to the root account.

After the Cancun fork, SELFDESTRUCT will only work if it is executed in the same transaction that created the contract.
So the operation can still be used during deployment time if you need to run some business logic just once.
As for security, technically there were no downsides, but for some existing smart contracts and applications (see again section EIP-4758 Backward Compatibility).
In adopting EIP-4758, the community decided that the benefits to the network were higher than the damage done to those existing contracts.
So existing pre-Cancun contracts using this feature will start to behave incorrectly, because the assumption made at design and development time were now no longer valid, and they where suggested to migrate to new contracts.

Just wanted to add as a comment, self destruct is dangerous since people can destroy their contracts and redeploy different code to the address which would create a major vulnerability, which is part of the reason why there is so much controversy around self destruct
